# Python Beautifulsoup4 all parser not working?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

so I want to scrape a website but the current problem Iam facing is that whenever I try to print out the element Iam scrapping it just returns an empty list. I know that the problem is that the parser can't find the class in the hmtl code. I tried all the parsers which are supported with Beautifoulsoup4 => 'lxmL' and 'hmtl5lib' but it still doesn't work. I even tried downgrading the version from 4.11.0 => 4.9.3, still doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
import requests
import random
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

products = {
    1: "Hoodies",
    2: "Sunglasses",
    3: "Couple-T-shirts",
    4: "Wall-Stickers",
    5: "Rugs",
    6: "Dog-Bed",
    7: "Claw-Cutter",
    8: "Fur-Remover",
    9: "Led-Keyboard",
    10: "Wireless-Chargers",
    11: "Powerbank",
    12: "Game-Controller",
    13: "Portable-Speakers",
    14: "Scalp-Massager",
    15: "Blackhead-Remover",
    16: "Lash-Products",
    17: "Makeup-Kit",
    18: "Air-Tag-Tracker",
    19: "Air-Purifiers",
    20: "Pixelart",
    21: "Yoga-Mats",
    22: "Face-Masks",
    23: "Fitness-Watches",
    24: "Resistance-Bands",
    25: "Air-Purifiers",
    26: "Cell-Phone-Mounts",
    27: "Wireless-Security-Cameras",
    28: "Massage-Tools",
    29: "Air-Purifiers",
    30: "Eyeliner-Pencil",
    31: "Water-Filters",
    32: "Slow-Feeder-Dog-Bowls",
    33: "Video-Doorbells",
    34: "Solar-Outdoor-Lights",
    35: "Phone-Grip",
    36: "Slow-Feeder-Dog-Bowls",
    37: "Pajamas",
    38: "Skin-Care-Oil",
    39: "Flasks",
    40: "Monitor-Holders",
    41: "Watches",
    42: "Rings",
    43: "Monitor-Holders",
    44: "Nail-Polish",
    45: "Rice-Cooker",
}

i = random.randint(1, 45)

url = f'https://www.aliexpress.com/af/{products[i]}.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.10000020initiative_id=SB_20230106091400&dida=y&origin=n'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
soup.prettify()
product = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'manhattan--container--1lP57Ag cards--gallery--2o6yJVt'})
productimage = soup.find_all('img', {'class': 'manhattan--img--36QXbtQ product-img'})
productprice = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'manhattan--price-sale--1CCSZfK'})
productrating = soup.find_all('span', {'class': 'manhattan--evaluation--3cSMntr'})

print(soup)

productlinkstring = product[0]['href']
productlinkstring = 'https://www' + productlinkstring[4:]
productimagelinkstring = productimage[0]['src']
productimagelinkstring = 'https://' + productimagelinkstring[2:]
productpricestring = productprice[0].text
productratingsting = productrating[0].text

producttitle = products[i]
producttitlestring = producttitle.replace('-', ' ')

productsstring = products[i]
productsstringright = productsstring.replace('-', '+')
endpoint = f'https://api.datamuse.com/words?ml={productsstringright}&max=18'

response = requests.get(endpoint)

data = response.json()

print(productlinkstring)
print(productimagelinkstring)
```

Comment: That likely means the content you're look for is populated by JavaScript, so it doesn't exist when you parse it. If that's the case, you'd need to use a tool like Selenium to run the JavaScript to generate the content. You can check if that's the case by checking the `Source` tab instead of the `Elements` tab in the dev tools. If it's only in the latter, that's your problem.

Comment: It probably isn't. It worked some hours ago with a html parser in a different code but on the same site. (Sorry, I don't have a save of that code). But I will try Selenium then.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, it is not only in the latter option.

Comment: I ran the beginning of your code and saved the incoming HTML to a file and checked it out.  I don't see any 'class' attributes in the HTML that would match your queries.  In fact, the string`"manhattan--"` does not appear anywhere in the HTML.  I had the same thought as @Carcigenicate...that the elements you're expecting to find are not in the starting HTML of the page but are rather added to the DOM dynamically via Javascript.  I could very well have done something wrong.  In any case, if you aren't dumping and looking at the incoming HTML, that's the first place to look for issues.

Comment: So I think the classes get changed depending on the size of the window. Maybe that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your parser.

Some notes about my tests:

- `i = 19` when I ran my tests
- so `url` was formed as  <sub>https://www.aliexpress.com/af/Air-Purifiers.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.10000020initiative_id=SB_20230106091400&dida=y&origin=n</sub>
- but when I ran *`print(f'{page.status_code} {page.reason} from {page.url}')`* to check the response, the output indicated a redirect somewhere

  > 200 OK from  <sub>https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?SearchText=Air%2BPurifiers&spm=a2g0o.productlist.10000020initiative_id%3DSB_20230106091400&origin=n&dida=y</sub>
- I also ran *`with open('x.html', 'wb') as f: f.write(page.content)`*, but when I open "x.html" on my browser, it [looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVhCL.png) even though the [products show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CBZf.png) (with the classes used in your code too) when I rendered it with [`IPython.display.HTML`](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/render_html_in_ipython_notebook/#rendering-the-selected-html-in-the-notebook)

This indicates that the elements you're targeting are **rendered with JavaScript**, and that's why they're not found.

---

The data you want seems to be [in one of the `script` tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Tac.png) though. I could target that tag with

```py
scriptTag = soup.select_one('meta[name="aplus-auto-exp"]~script')
```

and if any other parser was not used, the JavaScript code could probably be gotten simply with *`jScript = scriptTag.get_text()`*, but with `html5lib` parser I had to stringify and strip the tag name:

```py
jScript = scriptTag.prettify().strip()
jScript = jScript.strip('<script').split('>', 1)[-1].strip('</script>').strip()
```

---

And then I extracted the list of products with **[`findObj_inJS`](https://pastebin.com/UVcLniSG)**, which uses [slimit](https://slimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to parse JavaScript:

```py
itemList = findObj_inJS(jScript, '"itemList"')['content']
```

`itemList` contained 60 items. The first 2 items are prettified as JSON below:

```json
[
    {
        "itemType": "productV3",
        "productType": "natural",
        "nativeCardType": "nt_srp_cell_g",
        "itemCardType": "manhattan",
        "productId": "3256804896450950",
        "lunchTime": "2022-12-20 00:00:00",
        "image": {
            "imgUrl": "//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S39f71cffe79a4a6981083f57128103c9d/Anti-Gravity-Humidifier-Diffuser-Water-Drop-Falling-Remote-Control-Mini-Mist-Maker-Humidifier-Air-Purifiers-Droplets.jpg_220x220xz.jpg",
            "imgWidth": 220,
            "imgHeight": 220,
            "imgType": "0"
        },
        "title": {
            "seoTitle": "Anti Gravity Humidifier Diffuser Water Drop Falling Remote Control Mini Mist Maker Humidifier Air Purifiers Droplets Upflow USB",
            "displayTitle": "Anti Gravity Humidifier Diffuser Water Drop Falling Remote Control Mini Mist Maker Humidifier Air Purifiers Droplets Upflow USB",
            "shortTitle": false
        },
        "prices": {
            "skuId": "12000031580241123",
            "pricesStyle": "default",
            "builderType": "skuCoupon",
            "currencySymbol": "US $",
            "prefix": "Sale price:",
            "salePrice": {
                "discount": -1,
                "minPriceDiscount": 50,
                "priceType": "sale_price",
                "currencyCode": "USD",
                "minPrice": 26,
                "minPriceType": 2,
                "formattedPrice": "US $26.00"
            },
            "taxRate": "0"
        },
        "sellingPoints": [
            {
                "sellingPointTagId": "m0000063",
                "tagStyleType": "default",
                "tagContent": {
                    "displayTagType": "text",
                    "tagText": "Extra 1% off with coins",
                    "tagStyle": {
                        "color": "#FD384F",
                        "position": "2"
                    }
                },
                "source": "flexiCoin_new_atm"
            },
            {
                "sellingPointTagId": "m0000064",
                "tagStyleType": "default",
                "tagContent": {
                    "displayTagType": "text",
                    "tagText": "Free Shipping",
                    "tagStyle": {
                        "color": "#009966",
                        "position": "4"
                    }
                },
                "source": "Free_Shipping_atm"
            }
        ],
        "store": {
            "storeId": 1102377281,
            "aliMemberId": 2668032633,
            "storeName": "Yousmile Life Store",
            "storeUrl": "//www.aliexpress.com/store/1102377281"
        },
        "trace": {
            "pdpParams": {
                "pdp_cdi": "%7B%22traceId%22%3A%22212243c016730635978473504d06bf%22%2C%22itemId%22%3A%223256804896450950%22%2C%22fromPage%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22skuId%22%3A%2212000031580241123%22%2C%22shipFrom%22%3A%22US%22%2C%22order%22%3A%220%22%2C%22star%22%3A%22%22%2C%22freeShip%22%3A%22true%22%7D",
                "pdp_npi": "2%40dis%21USD%2152.0%2126.0%21%21%21%21%21%40212243c016730635978473504d06bf%2112000031580241123%21sea",
                "pdp_perf": "main_img=%2F%2Fae01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FS39f71cffe79a4a6981083f57128103c9d.jpg",
                "pdp_ext_f": "%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000031580241123%22%7D"
            },
            "exposure": {
                "displayCategoryId": "",
                "postCategoryId": "625",
                "selling_point": "m0000063,m0000064",
                "algo_exp_id": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d-0"
            },
            "click": {
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "haveSellingPoint": "true"
            },
            "detailPage": {
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "algo_exp_id": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d-0"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "utLogMap": {
                "original_price_type": "offer",
                "formatted_price": "US $26.00",
                "csp": "26.0,1",
                "x_object_type": "productV3",
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "hit_19_forbidden": false,
                "is_detail_next": "1",
                "model_ctr": 0.06788578629493713,
                "sku_id": "12000031580241123",
                "mixrank_success": "false",
                "custom_group": 3,
                "sku_ic_tags": "[]",
                "is_adult_certified": false,
                "mixrank_enable": "false",
                "ump_atmospheres": "none",
                "oip": "52.0,0",
                "selling_point": "m0000063,m0000064",
                "original_price_strategy": "sku_opt",
                "x_object_id": "1005005082765702"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "itemType": "productV3",
        "productType": "natural",
        "nativeCardType": "nt_srp_cell_g",
        "itemCardType": "manhattan",
        "productId": "3256803823899352",
        "lunchTime": "2022-03-09 00:00:00",
        "image": {
            "imgUrl": "//ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S5d14059b4d364bf5a41d2c08a5d6e735y/Portable-Air-Purifier-Anion-Air-Purification-Xiomi-Air-Freshener-Ionizer-Cleaner-Dust-Cigarette-Smoke-Remover-Toilet.jpg_220x220xz.jpg",
            "imgWidth": 220,
            "imgHeight": 220,
            "imgType": "0"
        },
        "title": {
            "seoTitle": "Portable Air Purifier Anion Air Purification Xiomi Air Freshener Ionizer Cleaner Dust Cigarette Smoke Remover Toilet Deodorant",
            "displayTitle": "Portable Air Purifier Anion Air Purification Xiomi Air Freshener Ionizer Cleaner Dust Cigarette Smoke Remover Toilet Deodorant",
            "shortTitle": false
        },
        "prices": {
            "skuId": "12000027730379754",
            "pricesStyle": "default",
            "builderType": "skuCoupon",
            "currencySymbol": "US $",
            "prefix": "Sale price:",
            "originalPrice": {
                "priceType": "original_price",
                "currencyCode": "USD",
                "minPrice": 20.8,
                "minPriceType": 1,
                "formattedPrice": "US $20.80"
            },
            "salePrice": {
                "discount": -1,
                "minPriceDiscount": 95,
                "priceType": "sale_price",
                "currencyCode": "USD",
                "minPrice": 0.99,
                "minPriceType": 2,
                "formattedPrice": "US $0.99"
            },
            "taxRate": "0"
        },
        "sellingPoints": [
            {
                "sellingPointTagId": "m0000040",
                "tagStyleType": "default",
                "tagContent": {
                    "displayTagType": "image",
                    "tagImgUrl": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S8cbad032762b405b8ebd8f30bca4bc83u/338x64.png",
                    "tagImgWidth": 338,
                    "tagImgHeight": 64,
                    "tagStyle": {
                        "color": "#FD384F",
                        "position": "1"
                    }
                },
                "source": "new_user_platform_allowance_atm"
            },
            {
                "sellingPointTagId": "m0000064",
                "tagStyleType": "default",
                "tagContent": {
                    "displayTagType": "text",
                    "tagText": "Free Shipping",
                    "tagStyle": {
                        "color": "#009966",
                        "position": "4"
                    }
                },
                "source": "Free_Shipping_atm"
            },
            {
                "sellingPointTagId": "1000013764",
                "tagStyleType": "default",
                "tagContent": {
                    "displayTagType": "text",
                    "tagText": "Free Return",
                    "tagStyle": {
                        "color": "#009966",
                        "position": "4"
                    }
                },
                "source": "Free_return_atm"
            }
        ],
        "evaluation": {
            "starRating": 4.4,
            "starUrl": "https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/S567d6bf538214abf95c1e5825c7e6a05t/48x48.png",
            "starWidth": 48,
            "starHeight": 48
        },
        "trade": {
            "tradeDesc": "1340 sold"
        },
        "store": {
            "storeId": 1101982761,
            "aliMemberId": 2657161543,
            "storeName": "BOYALIGE Official Store",
            "storeUrl": "//www.aliexpress.com/store/1101982761"
        },
        "trace": {
            "pdpParams": {
                "pdp_cdi": "%7B%22traceId%22%3A%22212243c016730635978473504d06bf%22%2C%22itemId%22%3A%223256803823899352%22%2C%22fromPage%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22skuId%22%3A%2212000027730379754%22%2C%22shipFrom%22%3A%22CN%22%2C%22order%22%3A%221340%22%2C%22star%22%3A%224.4%22%2C%22freeShip%22%3A%22true%22%2C%22shipSellingPoint%22%3A%22freeReturn%22%7D",
                "pdp_npi": "2%40dis%21USD%2120.8%210.99%21%21%21%21%21%40212243c016730635978473504d06bf%2112000027730379754%21sea",
                "pdp_perf": "main_img=%2F%2Fae01.alicdn.com%2Fkf%2FS5d14059b4d364bf5a41d2c08a5d6e735y.jpg",
                "pdp_ext_f": "%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000027730379754%22%7D"
            },
            "exposure": {
                "displayCategoryId": "",
                "postCategoryId": "613",
                "selling_point": "m0000040,m0000064,1000013764",
                "algo_exp_id": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d-1"
            },
            "click": {
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "haveSellingPoint": "true"
            },
            "detailPage": {
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "algo_exp_id": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d-1"
            },
            "custom": {},
            "utLogMap": {
                "original_price_type": "offer",
                "formatted_price": "US $0.99",
                "csp": "0.99,1",
                "x_object_type": "productV3",
                "algo_pvid": "77f9a225-26b3-4384-990c-3f411893324d",
                "hit_19_forbidden": false,
                "is_detail_next": "1",
                "model_ctr": 0.21320748329162598,
                "sku_id": "12000027730379754",
                "mixrank_success": "false",
                "custom_group": 3,
                "sku_ic_tags": "[]",
                "is_adult_certified": false,
                "mixrank_enable": "false",
                "ump_atmospheres": "new_user_platform_allowance,none",
                "oip": "20.8,1",
                "selling_point": "m0000040,m0000064,1000013764",
                "original_price_strategy": "sku_opt",
                "x_object_id": "1005004010214104"
            }
        },
        "config": {
            "prices": {
                "color": "#FD384F"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

You could write a function to reduce it to only the information you want, something like:

```py
def reduceProductInfo(origInf): 
    try: prodId = origInf['productId']
    except: return {'errorMsg': 'productId expected', 'orig': origInf}
    pDets = {
        'id': prodId, 'link': f'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/{prodId}.html'
    }
    try: pDets['title'] = origInf["title"]["displayTitle"]
    except Exception as e: pDets['title'] = f'!{type(e)} - {e}!'
    try: pDets['salePrice'] = origInf["prices"]["salePrice"]["formattedPrice"]
    except Exception as e: pDets['salePrice'] = f'!{type(e)} - {e}!'
    try: pDets['imageLink'] = origInf["image"]["imgUrl"]
    except Exception as e: pDets['imageLink'] = f'!{type(e)} - {e}!'
    if pDets['imageLink'][:2] == '//': 
        pDets['imageLink'] = f"https:{pDets['imageLink']}"
    return pDets
```

and then just reduce the whole list with

```py
productList = [reduceProductInfo(item) for item in itemList]
```

the first 5 items of `productList` would [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh5Jb.png).

If you want to go with this approach, you might want to check out my [`getNestedVal`](https://pastebin.com/NRxKRJPn) function as well - it's rather useful for quickly figuring out the sequence of keys and indices needed to get a nested value.

Comment: Your solution definitly works (Thank You! )but currently there seems to be a problem with slimit.     import slimit
  File "/home/opc/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slimit/__init__.py", line 2                                                                                                                                                             7, in <module>
    from minifier import minify
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'minifier'
 This is the newest version.

Comment: @OFENROHR100 did you just `pip install slimit` (that works ok for me so far) or `pip install git+https://github.com/rspivak/slimit.git#egg=slimit`? whichever you used, maybe you could uninstall and try the other one? beyond that, I don't really know - tbh this is something I've been rather afraid of for a while since many of my scrapers depend on this function and I've been too lazy to learn another js parser and rewrite it....

Comment: If slimit can't be used, I guess you could just go with good old fashioned string manipulation - I'm not very good at it so I can't think of anything more elegant than `itemList = json.loads(jScript.split('window._dida_config_._init_data_', 1)[-1].strip('=').strip(';').strip()[1:-1].strip().strip('data').strip(':').strip())['data']['root']['fields']['mods']['itemList']['content']` and it's quite risky since it could stop working with very minor changes, but it [should give the same results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47e1R.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly is your goal in scraping, but have you tried

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

After that, your code works perfectly for me and returns good urls at the end of the script

```
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004643645808.html?algo_pvid=36f2290b-a7f6-4a43-8d4e-cb427a255b22&algo_exp_id=36f2290b-a7f6-4a43-8d4e-cb427a255b22-0&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2212000030390398106%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21EUR%213.8%211.79%21%21%21%21%21%402100b20d16730874440116525d06ef%2112000030390398106%21sea&curPageLogUid=TO7uEnR4RcFE
https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/Sba697dac347c425bbbc16a0f71d8a534W/Mini-Tracking-Device-Tracking-Air-Tag-Key-Child-Finder-Pet-Tracker-Location-Smart-Bluetooth-Tracker-Car.jpg_220x220xz.jpg
```